# Simple table with background color and borders - hhline

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make simple table with different background colors for cells with borders.

I've read that you have to use `\hhline` in order not to get the borders overwritten but it doesn't work (some borders are missing).

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{report}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{good}{rgb}{0.80,1,0.51}
\definecolor{some}{rgb}{1,0.91,0.38}
\definecolor{bad}{rgb}{1,0.5,0.5}

\begin{table}
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.6}%
\begin{tabular}{| p{2.2cm}|p{3.6cm}|p{3.6cm}|p{3.6cm}|}
\hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
 & \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} \\
\hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
\textbf{a} & \cellcolor{some} b  & \cellcolor{good} c  & \cellcolor{bad} d \\ 
\hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
\textbf{a} & \cellcolor{some} b  & \cellcolor{good} c  & \cellcolor{bad} d \\ 
\hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
\textbf{a} & \cellcolor{some} b  & \cellcolor{good} c  & \cellcolor{bad} d \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{table.}
\label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This is an issue of your PDF reader. Try adding `\arrayrulewidth=0.8pt` inside the table.

Comment: Oh, it seems you are right. \arrayrulewidth=0.8pt helps a bit but some lines are thicker than the other ones and some get hidden in different zoom level. Why is this happening? Well let's hope it's gonna look normally at least when it's printed.